# How to pause/play Drupal Rotating Banner when Shadowbox opens and closes?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, shadowbox

In the header of a webpage sits a banner which displays a slideshow. An example can be found [here](http://www.denotenbalkers.be/). Now, when a user is on a page containing a photo gallery and he clicks a thumbnail a lightbox will open ([shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)). Simultaneously with opening the lightbox, the slideshow script should be stopped so that the user is not distracted by the background.

Summarized:
**Normal**: script for slideshow is being executed
**When a user clicks thumbnail** (with a certain rel attr "shadowbox"): the slide show script should be blocked.
**When lightbox is closed** (use Shadowbox's `onClose` hook?) the script of the slide show in the header should be re-initialized.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: There is only ever one script running at a time in Javascript.  You probably just need to cancel a timeout or interval.

Comment: You got any code to go with the question?

Comment: @ZeeTee I'm afraid I do not. You can find shadowbox's code via the link I posted but the slideshow is a Drupal menu and I can't seem to find the code that is creating the sliding.

Comment: But I think the click event is defined in jQuery's cycle.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Shadowbox you are using is **v3.0.3**, the current stable release.

The name of the other plug-in you are using is [Durpal Rotating Banner v6](http://drupal.org/node/766604/release?api_version%5b%5d=103), but version **7.2** is available for use.

You are absolutely correct in using **Shadowbox Hook Options**, `.onOpen();` and `onClose();` to interact with the Rotating Banner script. However, the Rotating Banner script doesn't have API usage documentation other than configuring the options in via a customized menu.

Examining the well documented JavaScript downloadable zipped files shows how to interface with the **Durpal Rotating Banner**, no matter the version you are using.

First, I do not use the plugin version of Shadowbox, only the stand-alone version from the [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com) website but this method should word for various Shadowbox plugins (e.g., Drupal, WordPress) out there for those landing on this answer.

If you don't have access to `Shadowbox.init({});`, use this script right before the closing body tag of your webpage, otherwise **jump down** to the next block of code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     window.onload=function(){

        Shadowbox.setup('',{

            // Besides 'pause' and 'resume' are 'prev', 'next', and 'stop' found in the jQuery Cycle Plugin (check inside jQuery Easing Plugin to see if it's combined).

              onOpen: function(){
                  jQuery('.rb-slides').each(function () {
                    if (jQuery(this).cycle) {
                      jQuery(this).cycle('pause');
                    }
                  });
              },
              onClose: function(){
                  jQuery('.rb-slides').each(function () {
                    if (jQuery(this).cycle) {
                      jQuery(this).cycle('resume');
                    }
                  });
              }

            // If you have access to Shadowbox.init({}), then place the above onOpen and onClose in there instead of using this script.

        });

     };

   </script>
```

If you have access to Shadowbox initialization via `Shadowbox.init({});` then use the `onOpen();` and `onClose();` portions below as shown.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

       Shadowbox.init({

           onOpen: function(){
               jQuery('.rb-slides').each(function () {
                 if (jQuery(this).cycle) {
                   jQuery(this).cycle('pause');
                 }
               });
           },
           onClose: function(){
               jQuery('.rb-slides').each(function () {
                 if (jQuery(this).cycle) {
                   jQuery(this).cycle('resume');
                 }
               });
           }

       });

   </script>
```

In my test environment, this works well for Shadowbox with the Base or jQuery Adapter interface... which for me is a download option (in addition to jQuery Library).

The above script will pause **all** Rotating Banners found on the webpage when Shadowbox opens and then will resume them all back when Shadowbox closes.

Comment: This looks very promising! One thing: I am using the script from shadowbox-js.com! I added it to my .info file so it gets loaded. Subsequently, I do have access to shadowbox.init(); but I don't really know what it should look like now. When I paste the code you posted from 'onOpen' to the line above the comment into the rounded brackets of the initialization, my editor tells me something's wrong. Maybe you could post an example of what that init-code should look like?

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I was looking at the .init() in the.js file, that was odd but it's acceptable if it works for you. I just updated the markup for **Shadowbox.init** that you can use as a replacement for the one in your .js file.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is great! Not only is it better to keep the focus on the lightbox, but also it increases the performance! Thanks a lot!